# How to commit to remote git repository

Tags: git, git-push

I am new to git.
I have done a clone of remote repo as follows

```
git clone https://myusername@something.com/repo.git
```

then I did

```
git checkout master
```

made some changes and committed these changes to my local repository like below..

```
git add .

git commit -m "my changes"
```

Now I have to push these changes to the remote repository.
I am not sure what to do.

Would I do a merge of my repo to remote ?
what steps do I need to take ?

I have git bash and git gui.

Please advise.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

All You have to do is `git push origin master`, where `origin` is the default name (alias) of Your remote repository and `master` is the remote branch You want to push Your changes to.

You may also want to check these out:

1. http://gitimmersion.com/
2. http://progit.org/book/

Answer (score 18):

You just need to make sure you have the rights to push to the remote repository and do

```
git push origin master
```

or simply

```
git push
```

Answer (score 3):

`git push`

or

`git push server_name master`

should do the trick, after you have made a commit to your local repository.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [git push](http://gitref.org/remotes/#push)? [gitref.org](http://gitref.org/) has a nice section dealing with [remote repositories](http://gitref.org/remotes/).

You can also get help from the command line using the `--help` option. For example:

```
% git push --help
GIT-PUSH(1)                             Git Manual                             GIT-PUSH(1)



NAME
       git-push - Update remote refs along with associated objects

SYNOPSIS
       git push [--all | --mirror | --tags] [-n | --dry-run] [--receive-pack=<git-receive-pack>]
                  [--repo=<repository>] [-f | --force] [-v | --verbose] [-u | --set-upstream]
                  [<repository> [<refspec>...]]
...
```

Answer (score -1):

just type
"git push"
if this doesn't give you a positive replay, then check if you are connected with your repository correctly.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You are answering an old question and you answer has already been given several times in this thread. Please only post new answers if they add value to the post.