# Git: Does commit affect a remote branch that Im tracking?

Tags: git, commit, git-branch

I'm currently tracking a remote branch (origin/implement) and I have the authentication to push to it, however currently I don't want to do such and instead I just want to commit my changes on the local that is tracking the remote. My question is when I commit does it record my commits on the branch I am tracking because I don't want to make things complicated for the branch owner.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to commit to remote git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364429/how-to-commit-to-remote-git-repository)

Comment: Committing will not update the remote repository until you push, but every commit comment will be recorded with your push. That way you can view a history of all your commits. You can use git add to add your changes to your local repository without committing code or making a comment.

Comment: @Buffalo `git add` only adds things to the local index/staging area, which is not part of any repository. See "The Three States" here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics The index should be considered highly volatile and only a temporary place to queue things for imminent `commit`ting. `git` will often warn about operations that will overwrite the index, but still, thinking of it as part of the repo or persistent in any other way is setting oneself up for a demoralising accident.

Answer (score 3):

No, unless you explicitly push your changes to the remote branch, your changes will only be in your local repository.

The vast majority of Git commands only work against your local repository (you can verify this by disconnecting from the network, and in general everything will work the same way).

You will need to `git push` in order to send your changes to the remote branch.

Answer (score 1):

When you make changes and commit, it will be recorded to your local branch.
Unless and until you push to server ( remote ), it will not go there.

Does this help?

Comment: Yes it did, Thank you