# Github - How to update my own repository?

Tags: github

I have a repository in my Github, and I cloned it on my desktop. Then I did some work in the folder. How do I commit those changes to my repository?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to commit to remote git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364429/how-to-commit-to-remote-git-repository)

Comment: 'git add .' For all your changes or 'git add <file>' then 'git commit' add a commit message then 'git push -u <your remote branch> if you haven't added an upstream for your branch yet. Otherwise 'git push'

Comment: What steps have you taken already ?

Comment: Since you're using Github, you may also choose to use [Github desktop](https://desktop.github.com) instead. I won't personally recommend to use it by itself though, since it's much better when you know how to use the CLI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below code is right, but don't forget to add remote address to key "origin".

```
git remote add origin <YOUR_REPOSITORY_PATH>
git add .
git commit -m 'some change'
git push -u origin master
```

-u – sets **repo branch** as defaults, so then you can push, just `git push`

Answer (score 1):

May

```
git add .
git commit -m "my changes"
git push origin master
```