# how to update my own project on github

Tags: git, github

I recently created a project and I uploaded it to GitHub using GitHub instructions.Now I have made changes to my project and want to update my project on Github.How do I proceed?

Comment: a possible answer to your question. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40273324/github-how-to-update-my-own-repository)

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43364619/5784831)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to commit to remote git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364429/how-to-commit-to-remote-git-repository)

Answer (score 1):

Add your local changes to a commit via

```
git add "filename"
```

Then commit your changes

```
git commit "Your message"
```

And push it to the remote

```
git push
```

Comment: You need to set your Github repo as the uptream for `push` to actually push there.

Comment: Thats right, but this should be already done if OP followed (as mentioned) the guid from creating a repo on Github.