# Create git repository on computer and sync with the same repository on github

Tags: git, github

I have recently started using git to organise my code projects and have created a git repository on my computer. I have also managed to create a repository on GitHub. I want to know how I can sync the 2 repositories so that when I run the commit command for the repository on my computer I can also update the repository on GitHub. In trying to solve this problem my self I came across the push command, is that what I need so after I run the commit command I can push the repository on my computer to the one on GitHub. Please can you help me by telling me what I should do here.

Comment: Yes, the push command is what you need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to commit to remote git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364429/how-to-commit-to-remote-git-repository)

Comment: Do I have to specify the url of my git repository or do I just specify the repository name in the push command. Also would I have to specify the file or does it automatically do it?

Comment: It seems you need to read a tutorial on using Git. You might have found one when you signed up on GitHub: https://docs.github.com/en/github/using-git/pushing-commits-to-a-remote-repository

Comment: I did read the tutorial

Comment: I just didn't really understand this section of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it using the push command and it was very simple. I should have been able to figure this out. I just entered

```
git push
```

Then when I went on GitHub it was all there.

Thankyou for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

after create a github repository,you are given instructions you can follow them.

```
git remote add origin remote_repo_url_here

git push origin master
```

Comment: That just adds it to the online repository its easier to add it to my repository on my computer first then push it on to GitHub.

Comment: if i understand correctly you mean that you will create a local repo first, then push it to github. for that you need to create a repo on github too and then use above commands to add remote. anyway your problem is already solved..